# Object Modify Problem on Dynamically Created Element EventListener

Tags: javascript

I ran into a very interesting problem during use event listeners on dynamically created elements using Vanilla Javascript. I will first define the problem and later post the code.

I create dynamic html elements using javascript and during creation process I add "click" event listeners on each newly created object. And inside this event event listener I change a different property of a GLOBAL object. I mean, when you click a dynamically created element, each element modifies a different property of this global object.

Problem occurs here, I dynamically select the different property of the global object. So for each element it modifies a different property of th global object. BUT when I run the code, I see that each element only changes the latest property of the global object. Meaning that each element changes the same property of that object and it is the latest property of the object. Here the code:

```
var filter = {1:false, 4:false, 7:false, 11:false, 8:false} //global object
var productsAndIndexes = {a:1, b:4, c:7, d:11, e:8 } //another global object used for looping 
function createEmptyFilter(){
  var hdr = document.querySelector("div.content .headers");
  for(var product in productsAndIndexes){
    var inp = document.createElement("input");
    inp.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    var filterInd = productsAndIndexes[product];

    inp.addEventListener("click" , (e) => {
      if(e.target.checked){
        filters[ filterInd ] = true;
      }else{
        filters[ filterInd ] = false;
      }
    });

    hdr.appendChild(inp);
  }
}
createEmptyFilter();
```

Every time I check a checkbox, I got filter = {1:false, 4:false, 7:false, 11:false, 8:true}. But instead each checkbox should modify its related part in the object.

Any explanation and solution about the problem is appreciated (although I am not 15 rep :) )
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your `filterInd` variable is declared with `var` meaning it is *function scoped*, not scoped to your for loop block. That means that each loop iteration will overwrite *the same variable*, so the click handlers all close over that same variable, not unique variables with different values. Declare it with `const` or `let` instead, and the `click` handler will reference the value unique to the loop iteration.

Since you're using a browser modern enough to support `=>`, then you probably support `let` and `const`; there's really no good reason to ever use `var` nowadays.

```
const filter = {1:false, 4:false, 7:false, 11:false, 8:false} //global object
const productsAndIndexes = {a:1, b:4, c:7, d:11, e:8 } //another global object used for looping 
function createEmptyFilter(){
  const hdr = document.querySelector("div.content .headers");
  for (let product in productsAndIndexes) {
    const inp = document.createElement("input");
    inp.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    const filterInd = productsAndIndexes[product];

    inp.addEventListener("click", e => {
      if (e.target.checked) {
        filters[filterInd] = true;
      } else {
        filters[filterInd] = false;
      }
    });

    hdr.appendChild(inp);
  }
}
createEmptyFilter();
```

Comment: I Almost understand but you say it is because var is function scoped OR it is because of "closure"? Since event listener uses its own function and since fillterInd is at closure of anonym event listener function it is scoped? And it uses actual filterInd variable not the value? BUT I got same result even if I use productsAndIndexes[product] directly inside event listener function. Although productsAndIndexes is a GLOBAL variable, it gives the same result as if I had used function variable?

Comment: It's because they're function scoped _and_ the closure is referencing that function-scoped variable. With what you tried, `product` was also function scoped, so as the loop goes through, the next iteration value is assigned to that same `product` variable. Hence, when the click handlers run, they reference the most recently-assigned value (the last in the loop).

Comment: This is also why using something like `Object.keys(productsAndIndexes).forEach(product => { /*...*/ });` is a convenient alternative to a loop, because inside that `forEach` callback, `product` is its own independent variable, so any inline functions inside of that would close over the distinct `product` value.

Comment: You are great thanks a lot, I got it now completely